# TCP Client Kivy App not connecting to Server

Tags: tcp, kivy, tcpclient

I have my server made from laptop and I use a kivy App as client to connect to this server.
When I use server and client on same laptop it works. But, I tried running it on mobile and it did not connect.

I used Google Play app TCP Client to check the connection, and it was successful. So, there is no issue from server side I suppose.

**This is my server.py**

```
import socket
import sys
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

def releaseAll():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    keyboard.release(Key.up)
    keyboard.release(Key.down)
    keyboard.release(Key.left)
    keyboard.release(Key.right)

def pressKeyboard(str):
    if(str == "U"):
        keyboard.press(Key.up)
    elif(str == "D"):
        keyboard.press(Key.down)
    elif(str == "L"):
        keyboard.press(Key.left)
    elif(str == "R"):
        keyboard.press(Key.right)
    releaseAll()

# Create a TCP/IP socket for server
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# name = socket.gethostname()
# print(name)
# ip = socket.gethostbyname(name)
# print(ip)

# Bind the socket to the port
serverAddress = ('192.168.0.104', 10000)
server.bind(serverAddress)

print("Server successfully created...")
print("Server listening at localhost at port 10000")

# Listen for incoming connections
server.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print("No clients connected with server.\nWaiting for client to connect...")
    connection, client_address = server.accept()
    print("Client requested to connect...")

    try:
        print("Client", client_address, "successfully connected...")

        # Receive 1 byte data "L", "U", "R", "D"
        while True:
            dataByte = connection.recv(1)
            if not dataByte:
                break
            dataChar = dataByte.decode('utf-8')
            print(dataChar)
            pressKeyboard(dataChar)      
    finally:
        # Close the connection
        connection.close()
        print("Connection lost from", client_address)
```

**And this is my main.py from kivy App**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import socket
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


# import sys
# class MyButton(Button):
#     def on_release(self):
#         new_button = Button(text = 'hello')
#         self.ids.float_1.add_widget(new_button)

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self):
        App.__init__(self)
        self.l = ""
        self.showData = ""
        self.flag = False
        self.layout = FloatLayout()
        self.new_button = Button(background_color = (0,0,0,0),text = 'Connected to Server!',color = (0,0,0,1),pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y' : 0.8},size_hint= (.20,.1))
        self.serverError = Button(background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0), text='Cannot connect to Server!', color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                 pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}, size_hint=(.20, .1))
        self.serverDisconnected = Button(background_color=(0, 0, 0, 0), text='Disconnected from Server!', color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                 pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}, size_hint=(.20, .1))
        self.img =  Image(source = 'bground.jpg',allow_stretch = True, keep_ratio = True)

    def build(self):
        #layout = FloatLayout()
        #layout2 = FloatLayout()
        #new_button = Button(text = 'hello',pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y' : 0.9},size_hint= (.15,.1))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.img)
        connectbtn = Button(background_color = (255,255,0,0.4),text="Connect", pos_hint={'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y': 0.8},
                            size_hint=(.15, .1), on_press=self.cconnect,on_release = self.ccnn)
        self.layout.add_widget(connectbtn)

        disconnectbtn = Button(background_color = (255,255,0,0.4),text="Disconnect",pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.8},
                               size_hint=(.15, .1), on_press=self.cdisconnect)
        self.layout.add_widget(disconnectbtn)

        upbtn = Button(background_color = (0,0,0,0.7),text='Up', font_size=20, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45},
                       size_hint=(.1, .1), on_press=self.up_press)
        self.layout.add_widget(upbtn)

        dwnbtn = Button(background_color = (0,0,0,0.7),text='Down', font_size=20, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.15},
                        size_hint=(.1, .1), on_press=self.dwn_press)
        self.layout.add_widget(dwnbtn)

        rbtn = Button(background_color = (0,0,0,0.7),text='Right', font_size=20, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.65, 'center_y': 0.3},
                      size_hint=(.1, .1), on_press=self.r_press)
        self.layout.add_widget(rbtn)

        lbtn = Button(background_color = (0,0,0,0.7),text='Left', font_size=20, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.35, 'center_y': 0.3},
                      size_hint=(.1, .1), on_press=self.l_press)
        self.layout.add_widget(lbtn)
        return self.layout

    def ccnn(self, obj):
        self.flag = True

    def cconnect(self, obj):
        try:
            # Create a TCP/IP socket for client
            self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            # Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
            self.server_address = ('192.168.0.104', 10000)
            self.client.connect(self.server_address)
            print("Connecting to localhost, port 10000")
            # conn = Label(text="Connected")
            self.layout.remove_widget(self.serverDisconnected)
            self.layout.remove_widget(self.serverError)
            self.layout.add_widget(self.new_button)
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.send_client, 0.3)
        except:
            self.layout.remove_widget(self.new_button)
            self.layout.remove_widget(self.serverDisconnected)
            self.layout.add_widget(self.serverError)
            print("Cannot Connect to Server..")

    def cdisconnect(self, obj):
        Clock.unschedule(self.send_client)
        self.client.close()
        self.showData = "Not Connected to server.."
        self.layout.remove_widget(self.new_button)
        self.layout.remove_widget(self.serverError)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.serverDisconnected)
        print("Disconnected from the Server..")

    def up_press(self, obj):
        # l.append(+1)
        self.l = 'U'
        print('Up button is pressed')

    def dwn_press(self, obj):
        # l.append(-1)
        self.l = 'D'
        print('Down button is pressed')

    def r_press(self, obj):
        # l.append(+2)
        self.l = 'R'
        print('Right button is pressed')

    def l_press(self, obj):
        # l.append(-2)
        self.l = 'L'
        print('Left button is pressed')

    def send_client(self, obj):
        val = ""
        if self.l == "":
            val = "Q"
        else:
            val = self.l
        self.l = ""
        try:
            print("Sending Message", val)
            # Send string as bytes to server
            self.client.sendall(str.encode(val))
        except:
            self.showData = "Error while sending data to server.."
            print("Error while sending data to server..")


TestApp().run()
```

Please help me with my problem.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> But, I tried running it on mobile ...

> ```
> serverAddress = ('192.168.0.104', 10000)
> ```

This address is a [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). One cannot access such a private IP address in the local network from outside the network, specifically not from the mobile network. In order to make your server accessible from the mobile network it must be accessible from outside in the first place, for example with the help of port forwarding or by using external forwarders like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). And then the client must use the externally visible address and port of the server, not the internal one.

Comment: Thank you, but this was not the case. I figured out that Kivy application extracted using buildozer has restrictions to connections. I uncommented them and it worked for me.

Comment: @MasoomRaj:  It is still per design impossible to connect to this internal IP address from the mobile network. It might work on LAN with WiFi but not on mobile network.